# How to set variable to string input python 3.5?

Tags: python, string, variables

I'm trying to set a variable to a string input that the user inputs.  I've done something similar similar before, by setting a variable to an integer input that the user inputs and tried copying that and just changing it from int() to str() but it didn't work. Here's what I have thus far:

```
import time

def main():
    print(". . .")
    time.sleep(1)
    playerMenu()
    Result(playerChoice)
    return

def play():
    playerChoice = str(playerMenu())
    return playerChoice


def playerMenu():
    print("So what will it be...")
    meuuSelect = str("Red or Blue?")
    return menuSelect


def Result():
    if playerChoice == Red:
        print("You Fascist pig >:c")
    elif playerChoice == Blue:
        print("QUICK, BEFORE YOU PASS OUT, WHAT DOES IT TASTE LIKE?!?")
        return 

main()
```

When I run it, it tells me that playerChoice is not defined.  I don't understand why it's telling me this since I clearly set playerChoice = to whatever the user's string input was

Comment: How can you call `Result(playerChoice)` when you have `def Result():`?

Comment: does your code compile, i see many errors while doing so

Comment: Are you aware that variables defined in a function are local to that function? Also, in your code you never set `playerChoice` (not even locally, since `play()` is never called by anyone).

Answer (score 1):

Your functions return values (good) but you're not doing anything with them (bad). You should store the values in a variable and pass them to whoever needs to work with them:

```
def main():
    print(". . .")
    time.sleep(1)
    choice = playerMenu()
    Result(choice)
    # no need for "return" at the end of a function if you don't return anything

def playerMenu():
    print("So what will it be...")
    menuSelect = input("Red or Blue?")  # input() gets user input
    return menuSelect

def Result(choice):
    if choice == "Red":                 # Need to compare to a string
        print("You Fascist pig >:c")
    elif choice == "Blue":
        print("QUICK, BEFORE YOU PASS OUT, WHAT DOES IT TASTE LIKE?!?")

main()
```